# Executing curl command in python script

Tags: python, curl

I am trying to execute a curl command in my python script. The curl command executes perfectly in the cmd terminal but for some reason when I try to execute that curl command in python script using os.system() I get an error stating:

```
'curl' is not recognized as an external or internal command.
```

Note that curl is already installed in my machine and so it works in cmd terminal. But os.system() also executes in cmd terminal so I am confused why it is not working.

This is my curl command:

```
curl -u svc-Automation@ai.com:Roboticsengineering1@ai https://confluence.ai.com/rest/api/content/494966599?expand=body.storage | python -mjson.tool > confluence_output.json
```

This is my code:

```
import os
import sys

execute_statement = 'curl -u svc-Automation@ai.com:Roboticsengineering1@ai https://confluence.ai.com/rest/api/content/494966599?expand=body.storage | python -mjson.tool > confluence_output.json'
exit_code = os.system(execute_statement)
if exit_code != 0:
  sys.exit(1)
```

Comment: Where is the `curl` binary located (e.g., what does `which curl` return)? If you use the full path in your code, does it work? Alternately, you could just implement this all in Python using the `requests` and `json` modules. You don't need to call out to an external command.

Comment: How do you run this code? Are you running as `sudo` or something?

Comment: And what is the purpose of this? Do you just want `curl` to print out the results to the console? Or do you want to actually do something with the response? If the later, I suggest you look at the `requests` library to do this directly in Python.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I want to gather the data from the response for parsing. Would you mind telling me how to convert that curl command into a request in python?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice The page I am trying to access also needs authentication with the username and password I included so how do I add that facility to request in python

Comment: Did you just post your username and password on a public website where anyone can see it? You should change your password immediately.

Comment: We won't write code for you, but you'll find lots of examples involving `requests` and fetching JSON data here on stackoverflow and elsewhere. Maybe spend some time trying to put together a solution and then update this question if you run into difficulties.

Comment: To answer your question, I suggest you read the requests documentation to see if it provides the functionality you need. If it does, it will be much easier to consume the responses.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice ok sure. I am looking through it and will post my answer shortly. BTW the link, username, password are all fictional in my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of executing curl command I used the python requests to gather my data for parsing.

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

# Making a get request
response = requests.get('https://confluence.ai.com/rest/api/content/494966599?expand=body.storage',
                        auth=HTTPBasicAuth('svc-Automation@ai.com', 'Roboticsengineering1@ai')).json()

# print request object
print(response)
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @larsks, and I'd emphasize the advantages of the `requests` module over using `os.sys`. One of the chief advantages is that using `requests` will allow you to control the GET request and its response with more precision, and that, in turn, will make it easier to troubleshoot any errors. For example, all you need is

```
r = requests.get("https://your-url-here", timeout=(30, 120))
```

to ensure that the call raises specific errors for connecting and responding.  Further, `requests` also makes it easier to transmit parameters to the server:

```
r = requests.get("https://your-url-here", 
                 timeout=(30, 120),
                 params={'expand':'body.storage'})
```

Parameters are also available for authentication:

```
r = requests.get("https://your-url-here", 
                 timeout=(30, 120),
                 params={'expand':'body.storage'}
                 auth=('user', 'pass'))
```

You can find much of what you need here: https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/